# Shorter way to apply transform to matrix containing vectors in Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen

Is there a shorter way to apply the transform?

```
auto vecs = Matrix<float, Dynamic, 3>(); //vector in each row.
Affine3f transform = ...; // some Affine3 transform

for (int r = 0; r < vecs.rows(); r++) {
    Vector3f v = vecs.row(r);
    v = transform * v;
    vecs.row(r) = v;
}
```

Comment: By shorter do you mean something like condensing the three lines in your for loop down to one? -- `vecs.row(r) *= transform`?

Comment: @JohnnyHenly That's equivalent to `vecs.row(r) = vecs.row(r) * transform;` which, in general, is not equivalent!

Comment: For loop looks very superflous for a matrix library like eigen.  i would expect there is some neater function that collapses the for loop into a single function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JE42 is right, for loops are almost never necessary with Eigen.
It is certainly possible to simplify. However, note that `transform * v` in your case is not a simple multiplication but an affine transformation equivalent to `transform.linear() * v + transform.translation()`. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialGeometry.html

Also, your "points" are rows, so additional transposes are needed.

In sum, (without actually compiling or testing it) your calculation should be equivalent to

```
vecs.transpose() = (transform.linear() * vecs.transpose()).array() + transform.translation();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly apply an `Affine` transform to a set of column vectors stored in a matrix. Since your vectors are arranged on a per row basis, you need to transpose the matrix. Your for-loop thus reduces to:

```
vecs.transpose() = transform * vecs.transpose();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me. It was taken from this [tutorial](https://dritchie.github.io/csci2240/assignments/eigen_tutorial.pdf).
The solutions provided above didn't work for me. I didn't have transposed matrix like the OP though.

Here is the code:

```html
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Geometry>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main() {
    float arrVertices[] = { -1.0 , -1.0 , -1.0 ,
    1.0 , -1.0 , -1.0 ,
    1.0 , 1.0 , -1.0 ,
    -1.0 , 1.0 , -1.0 ,
    -1.0 , -1.0 , 1.0 ,
    1.0 , -1.0 , 1.0 ,
    1.0 , 1.0 , 1.0 ,
    -1.0 , 1.0 , 1.0 };

    MatrixXf mVertices = Map < Matrix <float, 3, 8 > >(arrVertices);
    Transform <float, 3, Affine > t = Transform <float, 3, Affine >::Identity();
    t.scale(0.8f);

    t.rotate(AngleAxisf(0.25f * EIGEN_PI, Vector3f::UnitX()));

    t.translate(Vector3f(1.5, 10.2, -5.1));
    cout << t * mVertices.colwise().homogeneous() << endl;
}
```

Note I am using EIGEN_PI instead of M_PI as was used in the original document.

This description from the referred document should also help understand the last line of the code: "See how storing the vertices as columns of a matrix allows us to transform all vertices with a single matrix multiplication. To do this, however, the inner dimensions of the transformation matrix, and the vertex matrix have to match. t uses homogeneous coordinates, and so a 3-dimensional transformation is represented as a 4x4 matrix. To match these dimensions, we homogenize each column of our vertex matrix
by using the colwise() method."